# Loopback 3: Multiple HasOne relation on one model

Tags: loopback

So, I [opened an issue her](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/4292)e, coz in my opinion it should work as I think... but might be wrong so looking for another way

So, pretty much I have two models, Wedding and Person. The Wedding one has these relations set:

```
"people": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "person",
  "foreignKey": "",
  "options": {
    "nestRemoting": true
  }
},
"partner1": {
  "type": "hasOne",
  "model": "person",
  "foreignKey": ""
},
"partner2": {
  "type": "hasOne",
  "model": "person",
  "foreignKey": ""
}
```

And one of my wedding documents looks like this (I am using mongoDB if you cannot tell):

```
{
  "_id": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca5",
  "date": "2019-12-04T10:37:42.000Z",
  "userId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca4",
  "created": "2019-12-04T10:37:42.720Z",
  "partner1Id": "5de78c77f89d1a8ad4091ca6",
  "partner2Id": "5de78c77f89d1a8ad4091ca7"
}
```

So, when I set include filter and do:

```
{ "include": ["partner1", "partner2"]}
```

in my loopback API explorer on
http://localhost:3000/api/weddings/5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca5

I get:

```
{
  "date": "2019-12-04T10:37:42.000Z",
  "id": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca5",
  "userId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca4",
  "created": "2019-12-04T10:37:42.720Z",
  "partner1Id": "5de78c77f89d1a8ad4091ca6",
  "partner2Id": "5de78c77f89d1a8ad4091ca7",
  "partner1": {
    "id": "5de78c77f89d1a8ad4091ca7",
    "fullName": "Jessica Alba",
    "spouse": "spouse2",
    "contacts": [],
    "verified": false,
    "created": "2019-12-04T10:37:43.292Z",
    "updated": "2019-12-04T10:37:43.292Z",
    "userId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca4",
    "weddingId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca5"
  },
  "partner2": {
    "id": "5de78c77f89d1a8ad4091ca7",
    "fullName": "Jessica Alba",
    "spouse": "spouse2",
    "contacts": [],
    "verified": false,
    "created": "2019-12-04T10:37:43.292Z",
    "updated": "2019-12-04T10:37:43.292Z",
    "userId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca4",
    "weddingId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca5"
  }
}
```

But, I am expecting this:

```
{
  "date": "2019-12-04T10:37:42.000Z",
  "id": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca5",
  "userId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca4",
  "created": "2019-12-04T10:37:42.720Z",
  "partner1Id": "5de78c77f89d1a8ad4091ca6",
  "partner2Id": "5de78c77f89d1a8ad4091ca7",
  "partner1": {
    "id": "5de78c77f89d1a8ad4091ca6",
    "fullName": "Michael Knight",
    "spouse": "spouse1",
    "contacts": [],
    "verified": false,
    "created": "2019-12-04T10:37:43.292Z",
    "updated": "2019-12-04T10:37:43.292Z",
    "userId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca4",
    "weddingId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca5"
  },
  "partner2": {
    "id": "5de78c77f89d1a8ad4091ca7",
    "fullName": "Jessica Alba",
    "spouse": "spouse2",
    "contacts": [],
    "verified": false,
    "created": "2019-12-04T10:37:43.292Z",
    "updated": "2019-12-04T10:37:43.292Z",
    "userId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca4",
    "weddingId": "5de78c76f89d1a8ad4091ca5"
  }
}
```

Any ideas as of why? why do I get the same two records for partner1 and partner2?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "hasOne",  use "belongsTo".